# using curl to execute paypal payment

Tags: curl, paypal, coldfusion

I want to execute pay-pal call using curl because we are on old ColdFusion version using Linux

I have this on my code which is giving me peer authentication error due to the java version we had on our machine

```
<cffunction name="doHttppost" access="public" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="requestData" type="struct" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="serverURL" type="string" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="useProxy" type="boolean" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="proxyName" type="string" required="no" >
    <cfargument name="proxyPort" type="string" required="no" >

    <cfif useProxy is "true">
        <CFHTTP URL="#serverURL#" METHOD="POST" proxyserver=#proxyName# proxyport="#proxyPort#">
          <cfloop collection=#requestData# item="key">
              <CFHTTPPARAM NAME="#key#" VALUE="#requestData[key]#" TYPE="FormField" ENCODED="YES">
          </cfloop>
        </CFHTTP>
    <cfelse>
        <CFHTTP URL="#serverURL#" METHOD="POST">
          <cfloop collection=#requestData# item="key">
              <CFHTTPPARAM NAME="#key#" VALUE="#requestData[key]#" TYPE="FormField" ENCODED="YES">
          </cfloop>
        </CFHTTP>
    </cfif>
    <cfdump var="#cfhttp#" abort>
    <cfreturn #cfhttp.FileContent#>
</cffunction>
```

I am trying to use this:

```
<cfscript>
function structToList(s) {
    var delim = "&";
    var i = 0;
    var newArray = structKeyArray(arguments.s);

    if (arrayLen(arguments) gt 1) delim = arguments[2];

    for(i=1;i lte structCount(arguments.s);i=i+1) newArray[i] = newArray[i] & "=" & arguments.s[newArray[i]];

    return arraytoList(newArray,delim);
}
</cfscript>
```

The following is the Call to the API using CURL Command

```
<CFSET requestData.USER = "#variables.pp_username#">
<CFSET requestData.PWD = "#variables.pp_password#">
<CFSET requestData.SIGNATURE = "#variables.pp_signature#">
<CFSET requestData.SUBJECT = "">
<CFSET requestData.VERSION = "#variables.pp_version#">
<CFSET requestData.METHOD = "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile">
<cfset sURL = structToList(requestData)>
<cfset targ = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp/ -d "#sURL#"'>
<cfexecute name = "/bin/curl" arguments = "#targ#" timeout = "10" variable = "tdata" />
<cfdump var="#tdata#">
```

But nothing seem to be working, it is just giving me a blank page, and i tried everything i can think of, probably

URL:

```
<cfset sendURL = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp SUBJECT=&CANCELURL=https://www.website.com/membership/&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=Monthly Subscription&NOSHIPPING=1&AMT=4.95&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Central Subscription&PWD=1306278099&VERSION=72.0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=4.95&SIGNATURE=ADJN1tvFsnuWAZo61FL-QGJSk-epGHRrOb6EVH8C&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Monthly Subscription&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=4.95&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=4.95&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=Month495&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=8B523DA2-DB69-EDDC-F1524640267728B5&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=sale&RETURNURL=https://www.website.com/membership/thanks.cfm&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=4.95&USER=1306278086_biz_api1.ignitegt.com&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Monthly Subscription&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=8B523DA2-DB69-EDDC-F1524640267728B5&METHOD=expressCheckout&L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments">
```

error I am getting is:

```
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Comment: Does your curl command work directly from the server via a command prompt? Are there any errors in the ColdFusion logs? Is the code getting to your `cfexecute` statement or is it failing before that? Wrap your `cfexecute` line with a `cftry` `cfcatch` block to catch any errors.

Comment: i gave it a shot but if i run it everytime, i get method not found, here is the url

Comment: What is "it"?  Start with the basics.  As Miguel-F mentioned, try and run the curl command *via a command prompt* first (most likely the API has a working curl example). There is no point adding CF to the mix until after you get it working from a command prompt.

Comment: Hmm, OK let me try and see and find an example of curl command in paypal